# Deleting account in Firebase on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

when I try to delete account in Firebase with `FirebaseUser#delete()` method in Firebase Android SDK I receive `FirebaseException. An internal error has occurred. [ CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN ]` instead of `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException` that is descriped here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#delete(). It is hard to develop with because `FirebaseException` has no method to fetch an error code. Version of Firebase SDK: 11.4.2. Is it a bug or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

*user.delete();* the method will only work when a user has signed in recently. If credentials are older than the certain threshold then this method will not allow deletion of the user from Firebase. You can overcome this by signing out and then sign in and then delete the user. 
You require new credentials for *reauthenticate();* method. I hope it helps.

Comment: I know how it works, it's easy. Please read my post once again. The issue is that the firebase documentation does not match the code.